# Android Kernel Compilation - Files

Tags: android, linux, compilation, filesystems, kernel

Good day for you. I just started to learn and work with android kernel development or internals. I purchased a development board on-line that uses AM3359 - TI Processor. Works fine with factory Images and I booted from SD_CARD.

Later I read the documentation and I tried to compile the kernel. Everything went well as expected. I do have a little questions that I would like to clear it regarding the files that were created.

I had a section in documentation in which I was asked to Create a Root FileSystem which gave me a file called **ubi.img** - What is this file ?

Later I was asked to create a tarball file providing the roots path which created me an other file **rootfs.tar.bz2** - What is this file ?

My question is... both the files used the files from **rootfs** directory to create these files. What are these files for? What exactly ubi.img does and what is it used for? Is it used for flashing it to nand and rootfs.tar.bz2 is to boot if I am booting from SD_CARD ???

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about AM3359 - TI Processor, but on most smartphones and also in the linux kernel requires a ramdisk which is usually compressed mostly it's a .gz file.
According to my experience when the file is decompressed and usually it contains hardware initialization routines which the kernel runs first during startup.
The .img files are where everything is stored.

Most commonly :
BOOT.img  - Read Only Contains ramdisk and 
            the rootfs this are usually zImage + rootfs.tar.bz2

System.img- Also read only although can be remounted as read+write Contains 
            the operating system files e.g binaries like su, busybox etc.

Userdata.img- This is where all the users data and settings are stored.

The above are all that's necessary to get a system up and running.But we might have others such as Uboot.img Preloader etc, it varies depending on the platform.